# Wordpress - Unable to use variable

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, forms, hook

Testing out Wordpress on WAMP by creating a basic plugin.
Scenario:

Created an Admin panel with a form that just contains a text area and button. The form will be used to insert JavaScript code and this code will be placed in the header of all pages. I'm having issues trying to access the text area value within function post_tag. Code below:

```
<?php

add_action('admin_menu', 'setup_menu'); 

function setup_menu(){

    add_menu_page( 'Tag Menu', 'Tag Menu', 'manage_options', 'tag-menu', 'html_form' );
}

function html_form(){

    echo '<h1>JavaScript Tag</h1>';
    echo '<form action="' . esc_url( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] ) . '" method="post">';
    echo '<p>';
    echo 'Paste your code below: <br/>';
    echo '<br/>';
    echo '<textarea rows="10" cols="150" name="tag"></textarea>';
    echo '</p>';
    echo '<p><input type="submit" name="tag-submit" value="Submit"></p>';
    echo '</form>';


    if(isset($_POST['tag-submit'])){

        $tag = esc_textarea(stripslashes($_POST["tag"]));
        echo '<p>Your tag has been placed on all pages!</p>';
        return $tag;

    }  
}

$value = html_form();

add_action('wp_head', 'post_tag');

function post_tag(){
   global $value;
   $output = $value;
   echo $output;

}

?>
```

Can't seem to output the value in $tag to the header pages.Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have any reason to structure it the way you did, try this, which is cleaner

```
add_action('wp_head', 'post_tag');

function post_tag(){
   $output = html_form();
   echo $output;

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Def cleaner, however, it seems to only post the textarea box within the header instead of the code stored in $tag :/